# BlueBoard software cannot run because "/mnt: No such file or directory"

Tags: macos, applications

I have connected BlueBoard to Mac. While running program with use of Terminal I receive this error. How can I resolve this?

```
mount -t FAT12 /dev/disk2 /mnt
mount: realpath /mnt: No such file or directory
make: *** [program] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

macOS doesn't have a `/mnt` directory/folder (it's not Linux)

You can fix this by mounting in a directory that you have read/write permissions to like your home folder.  Just make sure you create the directory first.

Comment: echo "flashing program : blueboardbasic.bin"
flashing program : blueboardbasic.bin
mount /dev/disk2 /mnt
mount: You must specify a filesystem type with -t.
make: *** [program] Error 1
Surajkumars-Air:blueboardbasic suru1994$

Comment: after making directory again it is showing this msg

Comment: plzzz help me out with this issue

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: I have connected BlueBoard to Mac. While running program with use of Terminal I receive this error. How can I resolve this?

mount -t FAT12 /dev/disk2 /mnt
mount: realpath /mnt: No such file or directory
make: *** [program] Error 1